Jumping to a specific PDF tag in microsoft Edge
I'm trying to open PDF document on specific device tag in Edge browser. By device tag I mean a link in electrical documentation (eplan) in my case to a sensor. This functionality works in Chrome. For example I want to show sensor with device tag '=CO+3110M1-1361B361'. Working url for Chrome looks like this:
https://.../ePlan.pdf#%3DCO%2B3110M1-1361B361
When I try the same link in Edge it just opens document at the beginning. Is there any setting in Edge to make it working the same way as it works in Chrome? I cannot use Chrome on customers PC. Also, in Edge the option in PDF View settings is disabled.

The main problem is that Those tags were designed by Adobe for Acrobat and never made public so there is absoloutly no common method between different PDF viewers as they all do their own "thang".
Perhaps the best way to see what one code is, may be to use a Modern historic Gecko Viewer that shows the full reference like this as an URL Address.

Many other historic viewers may no longer use that # ability even if they can load other HTTPS:// web based PDF including that one.

However for Chromium's and Firefox we need a different format.
The ref is on page 22 so that is universal to all viewers.
Firefox goto page 22 no problem.

Chrome/chromiums cannot goto a historic bookmark they stick at page 1.

However newer Chrome can replace 22 by searching bookmark text for a match
and thus open page 22 like this from this https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1025/ML102530301.pdf#01_B_R13%20Basics-10%20[480%20V%20Pump%20Schematic]

But for Edge with Acrobat we need to use the same as all other browsers (#Page=22)
https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1025/ML102530301.pdf#page=22&01_B_R13%20Basics-10%20[480%20V%20Pump%20Schematic]

